# Android app using large portions of the heap, no success identifying memory leaks

Tags: android, garbage-collection, dalvik, android-memory

I've got a relatively light weight app that seems to be using large portions of heap memory (in my opinion) and it doesn't shrink after garbage collection.

I haven't been able to identify any memory leaks by using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer. My knowledge of this tool is though very limited.

Snippet from LogCat:

(Note that this is only a small snippet from a log dump. The LogCat seems to output garbage collection messages almost no matter what I do inside my app, continously. The amount of free heap remains relatively stable though, indicating (to me) that there is no actual memory leak?)

```
01-22 17:04:51.672: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 721K, 10% free 8074K/8968K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 33ms
01-22 17:04:53.742: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 523K, 12% free 7977K/8968K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 29ms
01-22 17:04:54.012: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 12% free 7941K/8968K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 29ms
01-22 17:04:56.432: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 237K, 10% free 8116K/8968K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 22ms
01-22 17:04:58.632: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 445K, 10% free 8094K/8968K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 33ms
01-22 17:05:00.332: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 11% free 8013K/8968K, paused 1ms+10ms, total 33ms
01-22 17:05:00.582: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 487K, 12% free 7916K/8968K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 38ms
01-22 17:05:02.382: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 10% free 8107K/8968K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 23ms
01-22 17:05:03.882: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 10% free 8107K/8968K, paused 9ms+12ms, total 76ms
01-22 17:05:05.392: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 528K, 11% free 8059K/8968K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 35ms
01-22 17:05:06.962: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 489K, 11% free 7998K/8968K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 32ms
01-22 17:05:07.212: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 487K, 12% free 7928K/8968K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 29ms
01-22 17:05:08.832: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 226K, 10% free 8094K/8968K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 22ms
01-22 17:05:12.152: D/dalvikvm(16274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 453K, 10% free 8080K/8968K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 48ms
```

The above is a result of "heavy use", involving spamming on buttons and changing orientation several times. My concern is the fact that only ~10% of the heap seems to be free/left for further expansions.

For your information, the XML file representing the current fragment's layout (at the time of the above output) is a ScrollView with a TableLayout inside, consisting of about 25 TableRow elements, perhaps this is the cause for such large hogging of heap memory?

Is this something to worry about at all?

Please let me know if you prefer to look at some of my code. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The app is basically just one Activity containing two fragments. One of said fragments get swapped out with other fragments based on user interaction. 
Think of it as a typical Menu-Content app (like the default Android Contacts app). MenuFragment (Contacts list) on the left and some ContentFragment (Contacts details) on the right. So far there is not too much functionality
involved except for setting up the UI behavior. There is nothing happening in the background, no saving of states or similar. I've basically focused on making sure that
the correct fragment shows up when I select an item from my MenuFragment, that the correct layouts are drawn when a fragment launches, and that the correct fragment
is displayed when the user presses the back button.

Comment: What kind of app is it? Do you have many bitmaps (maybe even buttons with personalized images)?

Comment: The drawable-xhdpi contains 17 images, but they are very small, folder size is 37KB. I've got as many as 2 buttons (ImageButton) but I re-inflate "buttons" on the ActionBar pretty often in my different fragments (onCreateOptionsMenu()).

Comment: Without knowing more about the app, I think it's kind of difficult to give you good advice.

Comment: I edited in an update about what the app is, not sure if this is what you had in mind though.

Comment: MAT does not only help you find leaks, but also will show you what is consuming your heap in general. Hunt for instances of your classes (search on your package name) and see how much heap they represent, for starters.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply. I've now looked for instances of my various classes on the MAT and I can't find anything taking up a lot of heap. MainActivity (my "container" activity) is on top of the dominator tree with 0.03%.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heap will adjust it's size automatically based upon the needs of your app. Small heaps are faster on the GC so Android will not start you out with a 64 MB heap if you don't need it. While you're app is using a lot of your current heap, the heap is extremely small for an Android 4.x app. A bare bones 4.x app alone will use up 7Mb. From what I see, you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What you're saying sounds very reasonable and I really hope you're right. I will continue to investigate but if I still can't find any problems I'll use this as an explanation for what's showing up in my log and keep on developing in good faith :)

Comment: yea. look at your logs. you're heap size stays the same and the memory allocated goes up AND down. This is all to be expected. If you had a leak it would have an upward trend. It doesn't. I think you're chasing a ghost.